# threejs modify envMap on mouseover

Tags: three.js

Im new in threejs, I want to learn some about this library... but, in my opinion, there is very little documentation.

Issue is:

I have a SphereGeometry and I want to give It some interactivity through mouse events, I'm using three.domevent.object3d.js for "mouseover" and "mouseout" events to make scale property bigger or smaller. But I can not to modify sphere material when mouseover is triggered because nothing happens. My code is:

```js
    sphere.on('mouseover', function(event){
        event.target.scale.x *= 2;
        event.target.scale.y *= 2;
        event.target.scale.z *= 2;
        event.target.material.envMap = textureCube;
        event.target.material.combine = THREE.MixOperation;
        event.target.material.reflectivity = 0.15;
    }).on('mouseout', function(event){
        event.target.scale.x *= 0.5;
        event.target.scale.y *= 0.5;
        event.target.scale.z *= 0.5;
        event.target.material.envMap = null;
        event.target.material.combine = THREE.MixOperation;
        event.target.material.reflectivity = 0;
    });
```

textureCube is a bunch of jpegs for skyboxMesh, its code is:

```js
var r = "images/";
var urls = [ r + "px.jpg", r + "nx.jpg",
             r + "py.jpg", r + "ny.jpg",
             r + "pz.jpg", r + "nz.jpg" ];

textureCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls );
```

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add or remove an environment map from a material, you will have to add

```
material.needsUpdate = true;
```

Have a look at the "How to update things" doc: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-update-things

`three.domevent.object3d.js` is not part of the library, so I can't comment on that.

three.js r.52